# How to get record for every 2 minutes in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a data table that has entries for every one minute, it's bulky dataset. So I need to get every 2 minutes data retrieving `10 minutes dataset from last valid record`. All these data is used in the graph drawing, so trying to limit the number of records displayed in the chart.
eg for a sample looks like this:

```
DateTime
2016-01-01  08:22:00
2016-01-01  08:21:00
2016-01-01  08:20:00
2016-01-01  08:19:00
2016-01-01  08:18:00
2016-01-01  08:17:00
2016-01-01  08:16:00
2016-01-01  08:15:00
2016-01-01  08:14:00
2016-01-01  08:13:00
2016-01-01  08:12:00
2016-01-01  08:11:00
2016-01-01  08:10:00
```

Expected records result:

```
2016-01-01  08:21:00
2016-01-01  08:19:00
2016-01-01  08:17:00
2016-01-01  08:15:00
2016-01-01  08:13:00
```

How can I do it in SQL query?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Do you really trust that every row is there as you expect?

Comment: minute part modulo 2 = 1

Comment: First, you need a query which filters by the DateTime field >= CurrentTime -10 minutes (you don't talk about your db technology). Then, you must schedulle that query to be executed each 2 minutes, with a job, a task... or whatever you have available

Comment: It's sql-server 2008, and the sample date is in descending order. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server :

1. You can schedule a job in SQL Server Agent
2. Write a Loop in SQL and run it. You may alter @end_time calculation for increasing time limit from 10 to something bigger.

   ```
   DECLARE @interval int = 2, 
                   @start_time datetime , 
                   @end_time datetime   

    set @start_time = GETDATE();
    set @end_time = DATEADD(M, 10, @start_time)

    while (@start_time < @end_time)
       BEGIN
       select * 
       from [TABLENAME ]
       where [col] between @start_time and DATEADD(M, @interval, @start_time)

           set @start_time = DATEADD(M, @interval, @start_time)     END
   ```

Comment: Thanks for it. What I need is to get every 2 minutes data retrieving 10 minutes data from last valid record, then is it possible doing this way?

Comment: Change while loop to an infinite loop. Set `@start_time = getdate()`. calculate `@end_time` as 2 mins forward from `@start_time`. Add a condition if `DATEADD(M, @interval, @start_time) <= @end_time` and execute your select statement. Remember the select statement should finish within 2 mins.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

For retrieving the values you can use the following:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    YourTable AS T
WHERE
    T.DateTimeColumn >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -10, GETDATE())
```

And for your periodical task you can create a SQL Server Agent job that runs the previous query every 2 minutes.

Comment: All these data is used in graph drawing, so trying to limit number of records displayed in the chart. Thank you.

Comment: @Julia You might want to create a stored procedure to retrieve the data and execute it whenever you want to build the chart.